# Lion OSX: How to install libfreetype.6.dylib?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, osx-lion, homebrew

I am trying to install a ruby gem, but the installation process is stopped, because:

```
ld: file not found: /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How can I install this library? I checked the `/usr/local/lib/` and the library is missing there.

**EDIT:**

I ran **locate libfreetype.6.dylib** and got:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
/Applications/calibre.app/Contents/Frameworks/libfreetype.6.dylib
/Users/xxxxx/magick-installer/freetype-2.4.3/objs/.libs/libfreetype.6.dylib
/Users/xxxxx/magick-installer/freetype-2.4.3/objs/.libs/libfreetype.6.dylib.dSYM
/Users/xxxxx/magick-installer/freetype-2.4.3/objs/.libs/libfreetype.6.dylib.dSYM/Contents
/Users/xxxxx/magick-installer/freetype-2.4.3/objs/.libs/libfreetype.6.dylib.dSYM/Contents/Info.plist
/Users/xxxxx/magick-installer/freetype-2.4.3/objs/.libs/libfreetype.6.dylib.dSYM/Contents/Resources
/Users/xxxxx/magick-installer/freetype-2.4.3/objs/.libs/libfreetype.6.dylib.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF
/Users/xxxxx/magick-installer/freetype-2.4.3/objs/.libs/libfreetype.6.dylib.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/libfreetype.6.dylib
/Users/xxxxx/rubydev/sharelock-staging/magick-installer/freetype-2.4.3/objs/.libs/libfreetype.6.dylib
/Users/xxxxx/rubydev/sharelock-staging/magick-installer/freetype-2.4.3/objs/.libs/libfreetype.6.dylib.dSYM
/Users/xxxxx/rubydev/sharelock-staging/magick-installer/freetype-2.4.3/objs/.libs/libfreetype.6.dylib.dSYM/Contents
/Users/xxxxx/rubydev/sharelock-staging/magick-installer/freetype-2.4.3/objs/.libs/libfreetype.6.dylib.dSYM/Contents/Info.plist
/Users/xxxxx/rubydev/sharelock-staging/magick-installer/freetype-2.4.3/objs/.libs/libfreetype.6.dylib.dSYM/Contents/Resources
/Users/xxxxx/rubydev/sharelock-staging/magick-installer/freetype-2.4.3/objs/.libs/libfreetype.6.dylib.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF
/Users/v/rubydev/sharelock-staging/magick-installer/freetype-2.4.3/objs/.libs/libfreetype.6.dylib.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/libfreetype.6.dylib
/opt/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.4.10/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
```

But why system doen't find the library?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What library are you trying to install? Could it by chance be ImageMagick? Also, if it's a RubyGem, why is the post tagged with homebrew?

Anyways, I got this error when installing ImageMagick, you need to symlink `/opt/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib` to `/usr/local/lib`.

do this:

`ln -s /opt/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib`

Comment: This one: `libfreetype.6.dylib`

Comment: I am trying to install `rmagick` (+ ImageMagick I just installed, but maybe there could be a problem) and I got an error message about missing `libfreetype.6.dylib`

Comment: Uhh... could you help me, please, how to link it?

Comment: Edited it again, has instructions.

Answer (score 15):

If you're using brew, you can:

> brew link --overwrite freetype

Comment: I had to brew unlink first. This issue occurred for me after upgrading to mavericks.

Comment: This solution helps with my problem

Answer (score 6):

Gabriel F. Engel's answer almost worked for me. I had to do the following change:

```
brew install freetype
brew link --overwrite freetype
```

Answer (score 3):

Your compiler is trying to link to an lib at a location that doesn't have the lib, however it seems that you have installed it with homebrew. 
Try running 
`ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.4.10/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib` to create one, or you can just use the `without-freetype` flag to skip it.