# ImageMagick + El Capitan Unable to Locate Module

Tags: macos, imagemagick, homebrew, osx-elcapitan

UPDATE: Solved with the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586048/imagemagick-no-decode-delegate/10319327#10319327)

---

I have spent the better part of my day trying to get ImageMagick to work with Grunt, with no luck. Grunt seems to be okay, but ImageMagick not so much, even though I've run the test on ImageMagick.org to make sure that it's installed correctly (I used HomeBrew for the install).

I get this error when trying to run a task:

```
 Warning: Command failed: identify: unable to load module
 '/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-4/lib/ImageMagick//modules-
 Q16/coders/jpeg.la': file not found @ error/module.c/OpenModule/1300.
 identify: no decode delegate for this image format 'JPEG' @
 error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.
```

I've tried the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013474/lion-osx-how-to-install-libfreetype-6-dylib) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412208/imagemagick-and-os-x-lion-trouble), but none of them have helped.

(FYI I'm new to using the command line.)

Help?

Comment: Try running `identify -version` at the command line and see which image formats you have got support for. Try also `brew install librsvg libtiff jpeg`

Comment: Running `identify -version` produced a similar message: `dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/ImageMagick/bin/identify
  Reason: Incompatible library version: identify requires version 18.0.0 or later, but libfreetype.6.dylib provides version 17.0.0
Trace/BPT trap: 5`. Tried your second idea, then tried to run my task, got the same error as before.

Answer (score 1):

As with any `homebrew` problem, I would suggest you run

```
brew doctor
```

first, to try and sort things out. It is an excellent diagnosis tool.

Now, to your specific problem... mmmm... the `/opt/X11` part of your error message worries me because `homebrew` installs in `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/local/Cellar` so your ImageMagick should not be looking anywhere in `/opt` at all. I guess you have installed `freetype` via `MacPorts` or some method other than `homebrew`.

I would suggest you install the `freetype` stuff using `homebrew`, i.e.

```
brew install freetype
```

Then I would suggest uninstalling any other `freetype` stuff you have installed any other way. Finally, I would suggest you check your `PATH` environment variable and make it point to `/usr/local/bin` **before** anything in `/opt`. You will need to log out and back in for the new PATH to take effect - you can check your PATH like this:

```
echo $PATH
```

and change it by editing `$HOME/.profile` if you need to.

The `homebrew` version of `freetype` provides version 19 of the library and is therefore compatible with the `homebrew` ImageMagick version.

Also, I am a little disconcerted by the `X11` part in your error message - modern Macs don't really use `X11` any more and it doesn't ship with OSX. Let's see if the above ideas sort you out before worrying about that too much though - unless you know, and can say for sure, that you need `X11`.